# Python script inactive on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

when I run a python script terminal returns no error and no execution.

Tried also in python IDLE:
line by line is fine, but if I execute the content of text editor a new line starts in IDE but no execution.

No errors returned.

```
etc:~ peter$ which -a python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
etc:~ peter$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.10
etc:~ peter$ /usr/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

If ran from Python launcher:

```
etc:~ peter$ cd '/Users/peter/Documents/' && '/usr/local/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/peter/Documents/rename_files.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Nothing executed though. Not even the print statement in the file. The file content:

```
import os
def rename_files():
    #get files
    file_list = os.listdir("/Users/peter/Downloads/prank")
    print (file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    #rename files
    os.chdir("/Users/peter/Downloads/prank")
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None,"0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
```

Comment: Maybe you need a shebang as your first line to tell the OS it is Python... `#!/usr/bin/python` or some such.

Comment: You're just defining a function and importing something there, not actually executing anything. Did you mean to add a call to `rename_files()` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file imports the `os` module, defines one function named `rename_files`, but never *calls* any code.

At the end of the file, if you wish to use this code to do something, you need to call the function. This would go after the function definition, and make sure it is de-dented back to the left margin.

```
rename_files()
```

Alternately you can test for calling the script as an executable rather than a module, e.g.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rename_files()
```

This is a good habit to get into. It allows you to call the file as a script, immediately calling your code, but also you can import the file into other scripts, getting access to their functions, but not running them (until your other script is prepared to use them for something). It lets your file act both as an executable script, and also as a code library.